# RPi.GPIO.wait_for_edge(4, GPIO.FALLING) detects both press and release of button

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I've read the documentation for RPi.GPIO, and searched Google as well as SO, but can't quite find a solution to what is probably a very dumb problem. I'm trying to ONLY detect the edge of my button being pressed. But regardless of whether I specify to look for a "falling" or "rising" edge, the Pi will execute a command on both press and release of my button. Sometimes it executes the code a bunch of times. My code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

buttonPin = 4                 # this is the pin for the button
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)                 # pinmode
GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)                 #setting up my pin to be input w/ pullup resistor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:                 # loop
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(buttonPin,GPIO.RISING)                 # looking for a rising edge
        print('Edge detected')                 # this happens regardless of my button being pressed or released
```

Quite sure I'm missing something fundamental here, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a question about switch debouncing. [This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76667/debouncing-buttons-with-rpi-gpio-too-many-events-detected) is very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it programmatically with parameter `bouncetime` but, you have to use

`GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=200)`

or

`GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, my_callback, bouncetime=200)`

instead of `GPIO.wait_for_edge(channel,GPIO.RISING)`

or with additional hardware: add a 0.1uF capacitor across your switch,

or you can use combination of both.

More in [Documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/)

Peace

Comment: Thank you for this! I meant to mark this as the solution I used.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mostly fine, but you need some hardware knowledge...

With common switches and buttons, there's a thing called jitter.

[image]

One solution is to check for button state after a short period, usually a few milliseconds, and act based on the delayed result.

Comment: Or you can use bouncetime parameter

Comment: This is great info, I appreciate it. Marking @Koxo's solution as the answer just because I was able to use his code directly to solve my issue, but I appreciate the insight.